# Installing jupyter notebook on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can't install jupyter notebook on python 2.7 because I keep getting this error:

```
jupyter-console requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.6
```

Any help?

Comment: Install an earlier version (e.g. `5.x`) which supports Py2.7. Since `6.0` jupyter console stop supporting Py2.X.

Comment: how do I install an earlier version? `pip install notebook==5.0.0` didn't work

Comment: Preinstall `jupyter-console`, e.g. `pip install jupyter-console==5.2.0` and then see if `notebook` will install.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe pip3 instead of pip.

I do not know what I'm taling about, but since the one answer did not work for me (I had the same problem) here is something that did work.  I was about to try to make python 3.7 the default (but found much advice not to do this with raspberian), when I found this.

https://www.instructables.com/id/Jupyter-Notebook-on-Raspberry-Pi/

Seems they upgrade to pip to pip3? anyway makes the jupyter notebook install get past the error. You still get the error but the install seems to finish.

I have not used it yet, just launched it. (you need to use sudo a bit more than the above link says).